# How to find work?

Tags: design, studios, recording, effects

How does one go about finding work and getting experience in "the field?"

Comment: I moved country this summer, came back to where I'm from. Then moved city and am now in Paris. Last week I logged into Facebook, there was an automatic post from a board I subscribed to. Last Tuesday I met with the guy from the ad, today I sweat like crazy to get a boom and a shockmount, tomorrow I'm getting the script and we start shooting on Sunday. It'll be an ongoing weekend thing and it'll keep going as long as we learn stuff from each others and enjoy what we're doing. I was not specifically looking for anything that day I logged into Facebook, but I had been earlier on this year...

Answer (score 4):

Ryan's suggestion of finding someone to work with is a good one. "Beginning" may not be the right wording, but the spirit is there. Look for people who are at or above your skill level to work with.

One resource you can check is Meetup.com. Look for film/video production groups in your area and get involved with them, that site is pretty good for those sorts of things. You could also look for the nearest 48-hour film festival location and get involved with a group doing that.

That will cover your basic networking with people who are at or near your skill level. Foster and maintain those relationships, you never know what they can lead to.

On the more professional side, you should try to make contact with established company's/individuals that are in your area. I got my first internship at a professional studio by walking into every recording studio in Boston I could find, resume in hand. I worked there during my days off from work, and it made a big difference. With that being said though, don't allow your ego to get in the way.

If you can get a job photocopying or answering phones somewhere you might like to work as an audio tech, take it. Let them know you're interested in more, make friends with the mixers/editors, and ask to sit in on sessions that occur outside of your normal working hours. If they let you do it, you should be cheerful, polite, dedicated and stay out of the way/keep your mouth shut. Let your work ethic speak for itself. Remember the three big quesitons: "Do I **need** to say this now?" "Do **I** need to say this now?" and "Do I need to say this **now**?" *[hint: if the answer to all three is, "yes," then you can **think** about saying it.]*

I'd like to say there is more to it, but there really isn't...other than persistence and one thing that none of us have control over, luck. There's a possibility that you might be able to do some of this long distance/telecommute. Who knows?! The internet is a wacky place now-a-days.

**EDIT:** I neglected to mention looking into other local media companies that may not be directly in the filed you're looking at at the moment...which is funny considering I used to do dialogue editing for a company that produced web based compliance and ethics training courses. lol

Comment: @Shaun, great response! May I ask which studio you interned at in Boston?

Comment: @Jay - I started out at Renaissance Recording (which was sold several years ago) for a while, and later did a different stint at Rumblestrip Audio while I was in the middle of working on my master's. You used to live/work in Boston, or maybe know people who do?

Comment: @Shaun, Tom Love @ Rumblestrip is an old friend of mine. We go back to my time interning at Soundtrack. 

Comment: @Jay - HAHA. Tom's a great guy. I'm glad I got the chance to work with him; though I was more frequently in sessions with Rick. It was the folks over at Soundtrack who suggested I check with Rumblestrip at the time too (they had already filled up on interns).

Comment: Small world, eh?

Comment: @Shaun, if you're talking about Rick Sweetser, he's an old pal too.

Comment: @Jay - I am...figured you knew him if you knew Tom. I know they both defected from Soundtrack at the same time to start Rumblestrip. Haven't spoken to either of them in years, but I know Rick left to start his own business. Working with both of them was great, but at this point they'd probably say, "Who?" if you mentioned me. lol You know what they're up to these days? Send me an e-mail if you do.

Comment: Soundtrack was my first internship.  VERY intensive but they give you the opportunity to get a lot out of it.  I've also heard great things about Tom Love and Rumblestrip from multiple people.  Too bad there isn't more work in Boston!

Comment: @Dan2997 - yeah. i'd have loved to stay and work there, but there are too many students offering to do work for free just to have something to put on their reel. kind of hard to compete with that. you still in that area?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this same question not too long ago.

[Finding Audio Work - where do you look?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/finding-audio-work-where-do-you-look)

Might be useful to ya. 
Cheers!